# Understanding a proxy server and connecting to a web api via basic auth

Tags: c#, web-api, proxy

Hopefully this is the correct channel for such a question and my quest for further knowledge.

I've currently built a significant platform which allows clients to communicate with our `API`, which in turns allows "items" to be pushed to a print queue.

Most third party developers and app users have no problem consuming the `API`, and I only assume this is because they `authenticate` over `basic auth` outside a `proxy` environment.

We have one client, that appears to be locked behind a `proxy` of sorts, which prevents the consumption of a particular `endpoint`. I'm regrettably faced with the **407 - Proxy Authentication Required**.

I'm very keen to understand is this something the end user (client) should resolve by adjusting proxy security settings (if needed) or a developer problem?

I'm also keen to understand what is actually happening? End user behind `proxy` calls the `API`, to try and authenticate via `basic auth`, and then tries to authenticate via proxy-authenticate?

Ideally not looking for a fix but more knowledge on what is happening, so I can fix myself.

Comment: When you say `client`,  you mean `customer` or `http client` (app)?

Comment: @Laiv Yes, Customer, my apologize. I guess it can be interpreted in a different context.

Comment: Are you sure that is your proxy the one returning the 407? If yes. Can you track the http headers sent by the customer's http clients? Maybe their network configuration (topology) is messing with the HTTP headers. I have seen similar problems with websockets or clients getting access to internet via Vpn and/or Proxies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your consumer is probably accessing your API from behind a proxy. Do it's completely his/her responsibility to handle this.